# Use BeautifulSoup to Find a Custom HTML Tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, confluence

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to locate a Gliffy diagram on an HTML page. The source code of the HTML page looks roughly like the following:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Figure: Consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
<p>
   <ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="a9ab423b-b68c-4836-bffa-cdf1c5b95392" ac:name="gliffy" ac:schema-version="1">
      <ac:parameter ac:name="displayName">Sed do eiusmod</ac:parameter>
      <ac:parameter ac:name="name">Tempor incididunt ut</ac:parameter>
      <ac:parameter ac:name="pagePin">2</ac:parameter>
   </ac:structured-macro>
</p>
<p><br/></p>
```

I want to locate the `<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="a9ab423b-b68c-4836-bffa-cdf1c5b95392" ac:name="gliffy" ac:schema-version="1">` in the page, but not using such a general statement like `soup.find_all('ac:structured-macro')` because there are many kinds of macros used in Confluence, I want to accurately locate the `ac:name="gliffy"` macro excluding all other possibilities.

However, as this does not look like a standard HTML tag. I am not sure BeautifulSoup is the correct choice. Should I be using other libraries like **lxml**. Anyway, please let me know what library I should be using and what function, and how I should call to accurately locate the Gliffy diagram in this HTML page. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `xml` data you can still use `BeautifulSoup` but you need to donwnload the `lxml` parser, not in the standard library.

```
pip install lxml
```

Here an example on how finding code could look like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Figure: Consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
<p>
    <ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="a9ab423b-b68c-4836-bffa-cdf1c5b95392" ac:name="gliffy" ac:schema-version="1">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="displayName">Sed do eiusmod</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="name">Tempor incididunt ut</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="pagePin">2</ac:parameter>
    </ac:structured-macro>
</p>
<p><br/></p>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for tag in soup.find_all(attrs={"ac:name": "gliffy"}):
   print(tag)
```

Comment: I tried this method but an empty list is returned. I copied your code to run and nothing got printed back.

Comment: @ChinaMahjongKing strange, did you try also with `BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")`? Both should be supported anyway. Is the ":" character allowed in xml attributes or tag?

Comment: Neither statement worked. It seems that when we pass the `xml` variable into BeautifulSoup, the generated soup only contains the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
Everything else is gone.

Comment: I just worked it out. When we are using BeautifulSoup to parse the string, just soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml") will do.

Comment: quite strange anyway... I think that the ":" is giving problems see what happen when parsing the xml with an online xml parser, https://jsonformatter.org/xml-parser ... just return `null`.

Comment: now I got it, I misunderstood the question... it is and was a html page after all not a xml. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I should thank you for your drilling into the problem. Anyway the code you gave me is great.